# C# sqlite entity framework - map string type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

In SQLite in table I have column: Title and type of this column is string.
Now I want to map this table to Entity Framework in C#. And problem is with type string of that column because I cannot map it to string type in C#.
It works when I change in SQLite string to VARCHAR. But how to resolve this problem without changing column type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than
>   SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static
>   typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the
>   particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
>   container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible
>   with the more common static type systems of other database engines in
>   the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases
>   should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in
>   SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional
>   rigidly typed databases.
>   [SqlLite Datatypes Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

According to documentation the `System.String` is mapped to `TEXT` in SQLite so you cannot use string datatype for SQLite.

**TEXT**: The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

Here is a table that's showing .Net SQLite default type mapping.
[image]
For more information please see
[Entity Framework Data Types Mapping with .Net](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/DataTypeMapping.html)